# NGINX Setup (Rails App in a subdirectory)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, nginx

I'm using NGINX with Passenger to run a rails application on an Ubuntu server.

However, I'd like to have the rails app served from www.mydomain.com/store , and have
a wordpress install served from www.mydomain.com.

How would one go about setting up the nginx.conf?

Answer (score 0):

From [the official manual](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri):

> To do this, make a symlink from your Ruby on Rails application’s public folder to a directory in the document root. For example:
>
> `ln -s /webapps/mycook/public /websites/phusion/rails`
>
> Next, set passenger_enabled on and add a passenger_base_uri option to the server block:
>
> ```
> server {
>     listen 80;
>     server_name www.phusion.nl;
>     root /websites/phusion;
>     passenger_enabled on;        # <--- These lines have
>     passenger_base_uri /rails;   # <--- been added.
> }
> ```